# How to compare the colors of pixels the mouse cursor is over in pictureBox1 with the ruler of colors in pictureBox2 and highlight the colors?

Tags: c#, winforms

This image showing the on the left the pictureBox1 with image inside and on the right pictureBox2 with the ruler image. what I want to do is when moving the mouse around in pictureBox1 compare each pixel color where the mouse cursor is above with the plate of colors in the ruler in pictureBox2 and then highlight the color in pictureBox2.

I could do the highlighting when using a label but now I want to highlight the colors in the plate of colors in the ruler in pictureBox2.

[image: colors]

this is the code I tried:

and for the testing I tried to highlight each color in pictureBox2 ruler with black because if it highlights the same colors, it will not show it in pictureBox2.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Colors_Scanner
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Bitmap imageBitmap;
        private Bitmap imageBitmapComparison;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Load an image into the PictureBox control
            imageBitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\Ffmpeg Capture\radar1.jpg"); // Replace with your image
            pictureBox1.Size = imageBitmap.Size;
            pictureBox1.Image = imageBitmap;

            imageBitmapComparison = new Bitmap(@"D:\Ffmpeg Capture\colorslevels1.jpg"); // Replace with your ruler image
            pictureBox2.Size = imageBitmapComparison.Size;
            pictureBox2.Image = imageBitmapComparison;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Ensure the mouse cursor is within the PictureBox bounds
            if (e.X >= 0 && e.X < pictureBox1.Width && e.Y >= 0 && e.Y < pictureBox1.Height)
            {
                // Lock the image data for direct access
                BitmapData bmpData = imageBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, imageBitmap.Width, imageBitmap.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, imageBitmap.PixelFormat);

                try
                {
                    // Calculate the byte offset for the pixel at the cursor's position
                    int bytesPerPixel = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(imageBitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
                    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
                    int pixelOffset = e.Y * bmpData.Stride + e.X * bytesPerPixel;

                    // Read the color values from the pixel
                    byte b = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, pixelOffset);
                    byte g = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, pixelOffset + 1);
                    byte r = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, pixelOffset + 2);

                    // Display the color information
                    label1.Text = $"RGB: ({r}, {g}, {b})";
                    label1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);

                    // Find the matching color area on the ruler and highlight it
                    FindAndHighlightMatchingColorArea(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Unlock the image data when done
                    imageBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                }
            }
        }

        private void FindAndHighlightMatchingColorArea(Color targetColor)
        {
            // Define the color to use for highlighting (black)
            Color highlightColor = Color.Black;

            // Lock the comparison image data for direct access
            BitmapData comparisonBmpData = imageBitmapComparison.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, imageBitmapComparison.Width, imageBitmapComparison.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, imageBitmapComparison.PixelFormat);

            try
            {
                // Calculate the byte offset for the pixel at the cursor's position
                int bytesPerPixel = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(imageBitmapComparison.PixelFormat) / 8;
                IntPtr ptr = comparisonBmpData.Scan0;

                // Iterate through the comparison image pixels
                for (int y = 0; y < imageBitmapComparison.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < imageBitmapComparison.Width; x++)
                    {
                        int pixelOffset = y * comparisonBmpData.Stride + x * bytesPerPixel;

                        // Read the color values from the comparison image
                        byte b = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, pixelOffset);
                        byte g = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, pixelOffset + 1);
                        byte r = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, pixelOffset + 2);

                        // Check if the color matches the target color
                        if (Color.FromArgb(r, g, b).Equals(targetColor))
                        {
                            // Highlight the matching pixel area with the defined highlight color (black)
                            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, pixelOffset, highlightColor.B); // R
                            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, pixelOffset + 1, highlightColor.G); // G
                            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, pixelOffset + 2, highlightColor.R); // B
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Unlock the comparison image data when done
                imageBitmapComparison.UnlockBits(comparisonBmpData);
                pictureBox2.Invalidate(); // Force pictureBox2 to redraw with the highlights
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the result with this code is that it's just coloring some black color inside pictureBox2 and not highlighting the current color from pictureBox1 on the pictureBox2 ruler matching color area.

[image: results on the right in pictureBox2 it's just coloring in black in some places and not on the ruler where it should be.]

My KnownColor method:

```
private void GetNames()
{
    foreach (KnownColor kc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
    {
        Color known = Color.FromKnownColor(kc);
        colorsNames.Add(known.Name);
    }
}
```

now I want to using this method and logic with KnownColor to get a list of all colors names from pictureBox2.

Comment: For PictureBox1, since getting the color of a pixel is a one-off operation here, you can actually use `GetPixel()` (if the image is scaled, you still need to calculate the scale factor).  For PictureBox2, you should draw the colored rectangles yourself, so you have a constant reference of the colors used and their positions. Then highlighting the current color is a very simple and fast task. You might consider adding a tolerance factor. As of now, you're handling the whole image in PictureBox2, which includes a gray-ish background, similar to the background of the other image

Comment: As a note, if you don't want to use a buffer for the image data, instead of `Marshal.ReadByte()` you should add the `unsafe` keyword to the method and use pointers directly

Comment: @Jimi for the rectangle in picturebox2 i did // Find the matching color area on the ruler and highlight it
c = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
pictureBox2.Invalidate(); and then in picturebox2 paint private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(c);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 3, 3));
} but how do i know where to position the drawn rectangle and what size it should be to match the color from the ruler plate ?

Comment: As described, instead of using a Bitmap for the *ruler*, draw the rectangles (and numbers) yourself, so you know exactly what to highlight when you find a color, in the first image, that matches (with tolerance or not) a color in the palette you have created. You then don't have to *find* anything, you know exactly where the rectangle that contains that color is positioned (you know its bounds)

Comment: Maybe it will help you solve your problem if you focus on one step at a time. What I mean is, first solve the color pick from PictureBox1, and for example show the results in a label or a MessageBox, and only after that move on to your problem with PictureBox2. Divide and conquer.

Comment: @jarmanso7 the picturebox1 showing the colors on a label when the mouse cursor is on pixel is working already.  and i also understand Jimi idea to create my own rectangles.  I can do it that's not a problem.  what I wanted to do now mostly for knowledge too is to use KnownColor and get all the colors names from pictureBox2.  I did already a method in form1 using KnownColor to get list of all colors names.  but I want now to use it to get the colors names from pictureBox2.  any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: @Jimi what I wanted to do now mostly for knowledge too is to use KnownColor and get all the colors names from pictureBox2. I did already a method in form1 using KnownColor to get list of all colors names. but I want now to use it to get the colors names from pictureBox2. any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: @HaimHadad your question is too broad. If you are using this program as a learning exercise, that's great, but this is not how SO works. If you are *stuck* in a particular place with your program, then post a *new* question explaining exactly why it doesn't work and why you are stuck. You can't extend indefinitely this single question to tackle different aspects. Because the questions are never gonna end. Simple: 1 question, 1 post in SO.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.gethue?view=net-8.0